# Developing RDP for file transfer using UDP in c++

Tags: c++, network-programming, udp, file-transfer

I need help with how to design message formats, window data structures and acknowledgements and error checking for a basic file transfer program using UDP. I am looking for algorithms or some basic source code to help me with my assignment.

Here is the Server for the TCP that I did previously. I need window structures and retransmissions, configurations like packet number to drop, packet number to corrupt.

```
#include "unp.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int Read(int,void*,size_t,int,SA*,socklen_t);
void Write(int,void*,int,int,SA*,socklen_t);
int packetSend(int ,SA* ,socklen_t,int );
int recieveAck(int ,SA* ,socklen_t,int );

const long packetSize = 1024;

 struct Header
 {
  int seqNum,ackNum;
  char da[32];
  char sa[32];

 };

 struct Seg
  {
     Header head;
 char data[packetSize];
  };

    Seg *buffer;
    int nOfPackets;

int    main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in  servaddr, cliaddr;

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
servaddr.sin_port        = htons(SERV_PORT);

bind(sockfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    dg_echo(sockfd, (SA *) &cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));
}


void dg_echo(int sockfd, SA *pcliaddr, socklen_t clilen)
{
int n;
socklen_t   len;
char        *mesg;
    int size,bytesRead;

    while(1){
    len = clilen;
    mesg= new char [MAXLINE];

        n=Read(sockfd, mesg, MAXLINE, 0, pcliaddr, len);
        cout<<"File Name "<<mesg<<endl;



        int                 sockfd2;
    struct sockaddr_in  servaddr;

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(9878);
    inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1"/*argv[1]*/, &servaddr.sin_addr);

    sockfd2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    //dg_echo(sockfd, (SA *) &cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));
       socklen_t servlen =  sizeof(servaddr);
    // pcliaddr= &cliaddr;

       ifstream infile (mesg,ifstream::binary);

infile.seekg(0,ifstream::end);
    size=infile.tellg();
    infile.seekg(0);

    nOfPackets = (size/packetSize)+1;
    cout<<"File Size: "<<size<<endl;

    cout<<"Number of Packets: "<<nOfPackets<<endl;
    Write(sockfd2,&size,4,0,(SA *)  &servaddr,servlen );

    buffer = new Seg [nOfPackets];

    bytesRead = 0;
    int count = 0;

     while(bytesRead!=size)
      {
     if(size-bytesRead<packetSize)
      {
          int remaining = size-bytesRead;
          buffer[count].head.seqNum = count;
          infile.read (buffer[count].data,remaining);
          bytesRead += remaining;
       }
     else
      {

          buffer[count].head.seqNum = count;
          infile.read (buffer[count].data,packetSize);
          bytesRead += packetSize;
          count++;
      }
     }

      packetSend (sockfd2,(SA*) &servaddr,servlen,0);



    delete[] mesg;
    infile.close();

}
}

void Write(int sockfd,void* sendline,int lent,int flg, SA* pcliaddr,socklen_t len)
{
sendto(sockfd,sendline, lent, 0, pcliaddr, len);

}


int Read(int sockfd,void* recvline,size_t lent,int flg,SA* pcliaddr,socklen_t len)
{
int n;
n = recvfrom(sockfd,recvline,lent,0, pcliaddr, &len);
return n;
}

int packetSend(int sockfd,SA* pcliaddr,socklen_t len,int i)
{
if(i==nOfPackets)
    return i;
else
{
Seg *seg = new Seg;
seg = &(buffer[i]);
Write(sockfd,seg,sizeof(*seg),0,pcliaddr, len);

if(recieveAck(sockfd,pcliaddr,len,i)==i)
packetSend (sockfd,pcliaddr,len,++i);

else
packetSend (sockfd,pcliaddr,len,i);

}

}

int recieveAck(int sockfd ,SA* pcliaddr,socklen_t len,int num)
{

Header ack;
Read(sockfd, &ack, sizeof(ack), 0, pcliaddr, len);
if(ack.ackNum == num)
{
    return ack.ackNum;
}

else return -1;

}
```

Comment: So basically you want us to solve your whole assignment? Please write down how far you got.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would have been better if you had put in some initial effort, elaborated that and then asked where you are stuck. You need to learn sockets first to handle tcp or udp communication. Why do you need to use UDP? Is that a requirement? If so then understand that it means your file transfer won't be reliable unless your make it so yourself. Read a fundamental tutorial for writing sockets based client and server that exchange data. Then your next question would be if you should use a standard FTP protocol or not.

Comment: Here is what i have done before. Sorry about the editing.